# fancybox - page go to its top when clicking on Image

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

i'm using fancybox on my web,
When i click on image - the page go up to its top, and then the picture open good.
how can I prevent the page to go up ?

the call to

```
  $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect: 'fade',
            closeEffect: 'fade',

            prevEffect: 'fade',
            prevSpeed  : 550,
            nextEffect: 'fade',
            nextSpeed: 550,


            closeBtn: true,

            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'inside'
                },
                buttons: {}
            }
        });
```

Comment: Show us your code, how you call fancybox popup.

Comment: Did you try to use src of the image in the `href` attribute, instead of `#` (I guess this is the problem)?

Comment: i've tried and it's not OK.

Comment: Set up a fiddle to demonstrate the issue, it's hard to guess otherwise.

Comment: fiddler do you mean ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's OK i solve the problem, I followed the code in the jquery.fancybox.js.
when it gets to line #897

```
F.trigger('onReady');
```

the page got up to the top of the page.
I unmarked it (delete it) and now it's working OK.

```
/*F.trigger('onReady');*/
```

thanks

Comment: this works man. I still don't know what it does but I'm having the same problem. Thanks google I found this.